# How to increment count within foreach loop

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 0;
    List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<>();
    namesList.add("gaurav");
    namesList.add("deepak");
    namesList.add("anit");
    namesList.add("garvit");
    namesList.add("satvir");
    namesList.add("lino");
    namesList.add("gogo");
    namesList.forEach(names -> {
        if (names.startsWith("g")) {
            count++;
        }
    });
    if (count > 1) {
        System.out.println("executed");
    }
}
```

Getting the below error while incrementing count:
**Local variable count defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AtomicInteger` for this

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
namesList.forEach(names -> {
    if (names.startsWith("g")) {
        count.getAndIncrement();
    }
});
if(count.get() > 1) {
    System.out.println("executed");
}
```

Or using Stream API

```
long count = namesList.stream()
                      .filter(name -> name.startsWith("g")) // filter with condition
                      .count(); // then count
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't increment a variable.

[Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#stream()), [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) and [count](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count()):

```
long count = namesList.stream()
    .filter(name -> name.startsWith("g"))
    .count();
```

It's eaisier to read and understand, and it's less code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a stream as well. Use `filter()` to find the names starting with `g`, use `findFirst()`, to find the first one. If there is none, this will return `null`.

```java
String result = namesList
       .stream()
       .filter(name -> name.startsWith("g"))
       .findFirst()
       .orElse(null);
```